# 2D Array to JsTree compatible JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jstree

I currently have a javascript function that accepts 1 dimensional arrays and adds them to a tree object.

```
        var tree = {}

        function addToTree(tree, arr) { 
            for (var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length - 1; i++) {
                tree = tree[arr[i]] = tree[arr[i]] || {};
            } 
            tree[arr[i]] = null;
        }

        addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "c", "f"])
        addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "d", "h", "l"])
```

I was hoping someone could help me format it so that it returns the object into a JSTree compatible object found here: https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element in the array `["a", "b", "c", "f"]` you first need to create a node (one compatible to JSTree) and then add that node to the json object `tree` which we are building.

```
function createTreeNode(value) { 
    return {'text': value};
}
```

Now the function `addToTree` can be

```
var tree = {'core': {'data': []}};     //This initialization is needed

function addToTree(tree, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        node = createTreeNode(arr[i]);
        tree.core.data.push(node);
    }
}

addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "c", "f"]);
addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "d", "h", "l"]);
```

BTW: In case you are using BootStrap consider [jonmiles tree](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview)